# Pass Value between Html pages in Phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to pass value from index.html to other html file. how to use that value which is created in index.html in other page?

Comment: use javascript (jquery mobile or sencha touch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In page1.html:

```
localStorage.setItem("myValue", myValue);
```

In page2.html

```
var myValue = localStorage.getItem("myValue");
```